# Issue when deploying Jhipster 4.7.0 War file in WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, websphere-8

I'm developing application using Jhipster 4.7.0 . I have created war file. When I'm deploying to web-sphere 8.5.5 I'm facing this issue:

"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype"

I have changed class-loading library to PARENT_LAST because latest version using JPA2.1 and JPA provider for Websphere is  older.

It does not seem to Jhipster Issue. It seems Spring Boot Deployment on WebSphere issue.
Any suggestion for that .It seems that it's because of library conflict with Websphere but I do not know where should I trace it?

Comment: Does your app contain any Java EE APIs other than JPA?  The error looks a bit like something that could be caused by an underlying ClassCastException with a Servlet interface.  There are some libraries that you cannot include in a PARENT_LAST class application; Servlet is among them.

Comment: Yes I'm using JPA2.1 and after I switched to PARENT_LAST the error related to JPA2.1 library gone but I'm facing this issue. Could it be because of using JPA2.1 ?

Comment: JPA is one of the Java EE APIs that's usually okay to include, as long as you're also including an implementation (the WebSphere implementation can't be used in that case).  I'm wondering what OTHER libraries you're packaging in the app, besides JPA.

Comment: I'm deploying war.original war file that mvnw generates . Anyway when I'm trying  PARENT_FIRST , spring servlets is going to load but now I'm facing this issue :com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@507eb5ca[PF][app:CustomerView_war]
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST).
 at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1106)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:786)
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSource

Comment: I believe so  that your advice is correct and problem is totally related to JPA1.2 by this experiment .